# TP Link wr740n router takes longer time to connect internet and speed is slow

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Recently I have purchased TP Link router wr740n but having issue in connection and internet speed. Detail explanation of same is below:

When I connect internet cable wire directly to computer it connects immediately and the speed is as per my broadband plan.

Things I have noticed in router.

Step 1: All the wires are pluged in. Switch on the router then it will take 5 -10 mins to get internet signal (wan led will glow after 5-10 mins) and after connecting internet the speed will not be as per my internet plan.

Step 2: All wires are plugged except internet wire.Switch on the router and then when if I plug in internet wire immediately router connects to internet (wan led glow immediately) but speed is slow.

Step 3: I tested my router in my one of my friends house, there wan led glows immediately and speed is as per plan.

Step 4: I went to ISP office and tested my router over there every works fine. He also crimped my internet wire with new rj45 clip may be he thought rj45 connection may be loose. He checked my internet connect with some devices and said that internet connection is also fine.

Step 5: There is no hardware issue because even I thought it could be hardware issue and replaced the router.

Step 5: Called up TP link customer care to check if there is any manual settings which can be done in such kind of issue. But they replied no such configuration and asked me to check with ISP.

My firmware is uptodate. Please advice.

Comment: How exactly are you measuring speeds and what speeds are you measuring?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz my net speed plan is 512kbps and I measure it through speedtest.net. And also through router it takes time to open a simple rediffmail/google page.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz but when I test speed without router I get 512/256 kbps download/upload speed and with router 512/100 speed. But the speed is very slow like I have to refresh many a time to get a page load. My ISP have asked me to ping on 219.90.106.78 and check for request time out and said that request time out response should be at least after 20+ response. When I check it without router I get a request time out after 20+ response but with router I get it after every 3-4 response. And also when I ping google with router after every 3-4 response I get request time out and sometime after 1-2

Comment: Hi, If some one know how to resolve the issue, please help.